# QGIS run OGR command from UI feature form

Tags: pyqgis, ogr2ogr, qt

I would like to run ogr2ogr script from a UI feature form button in QGIS, that would start some SQL script linked to the opened feature table, store the output back to database and ideally reload the layer sources.

[image]

For example:

```
ogr2ogr -f sqlite -update -overwrite -geomfield geom -a_srs EPSG:5514 -sql "<my_SQL_query>" <my_database>.sqlite <my_database>.sqlite -nln <my_table> -nlt linestring
```

I have tried to search for some tutorials, but generally I have found some on creating plugins for QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

This use case should be covered by the answers to  [Execute ogr2ogr from python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154004/execute-ogr2ogr-from-python).

If it doesn't, please provide some more details on how the situation differs.

Comment: That could be it. How can I define this function to be run on click button action in the form? I suppose the script has to be loaded on form load (python init code) and also point to the button object name.